# How to split Array of Dicts into columns in clickHouse

Tags: sql, json, apache-kafka, clickhouse

I need to parse data from Kafka in ClickHouse using Kafka Engine, as example, I have created a table, in https://fiddle.clickhouse.com/0e89bec6-4e76-410a-9fc4-cf58ace5f34f,

```
CREATE TABLE json(name String, data Array(Map(String, String)) ) ENGINE = Memory;

INSERT INTO JSON FORMAT JSONEachRow {"name": "asd", "data":[{"id":"1", "name": "test1"},{"id":"2", "name": "test2"}]};
```

And I got 2 columns

```
name  data 
asd   [{'id':'1', 'name': 'test1'},{'id':'2', 'name': 'test2'}]
```

How to transform to take the following result?

```
name  id  name
asd    1  test1
asd    2  test2
```

Answer (score 1):

Does something like this work for what you need? `mapApply` joins the `name` column with the `data` column, and `arrayJoin` applies it to each element in `data`:

```
SELECT 
   name, 
   arrayJoin(mapValues(mapApply((k,v) -> (name,v), arrayJoin(data)))) AS id 
FROM json;
```

The response looks like:

```
┌─name─┬─id─┐
│ asd  │ 1  │
│ asd  │ 2  │
└──────┴────┘
```

Comment: Hi. thanks! It is works, but in this case it is transform all data in Map in one column. I have edited my question)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of storing the JSON as a `Map` of arrays, you could parse that data out into individual rows. This might make your queries much easier to write.

You could do something like this to each row as it's being inserted:

```
WITH 
    '{"name": "asd", "data":[{"id":"1", "name2":"test1"},{"id":"2","name2":"test2"}]}' AS json
SELECT 
    JSONExtract(json,'name', 'String') AS name,
    arrayJoin(JSONExtract(json,'data', 'Array(Tuple(String,String))')) AS row,
    row.1 AS id,
    row.2 AS name2;
```

The result is:

```
┌─name─┬─row───────────┬─id─┬─name2─┐
│ asd  │ ('1','test1') │ 1  │ test1 │
│ asd  │ ('2','test2') │ 2  │ test2 │
└──────┴───────────────┴────┴───────┘
```

(You can ignore the `row` column of that response, and insert the other three columns into your table)